# que estilos poner al xml

Tags: xml, odoo

Ya pude plasmar la informacion del popup en el informe pero ahora que estilo deberia darle al xml del informe ya que en vez de mostrar las tablas una sobre otra las encima en una sola fila

Adjunto codigo:

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <odoo>
<template id="references_report_view">
   <t t-call="web.html_container">
       <div class="header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
           <h3 class="text-center">Sales Reference Numbers
               <span style="font-size: 14px;"><storng>From</storng>:<t t-esc="from_date"/> <strong>To</strong>: <t t-esc="to_date"/></span>
           </h3>
           <div class="article mt0 o_report_layout_standard">
               <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th style="with:30%">Date</th>
                           <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                           <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Guia</th>
                           <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Cliente</th>
                           <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                           <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                           <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Factura Asegurada</th>
                           <th class="text-center" stlye="width: 10%">Ejecutivo</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                     <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="d">
                           <td t-esc="d['date_order']"/>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['otro_operation_type']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['partner_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['country_arrival']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['freight_type']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['invoice_amount_assured']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['seller_id']"/></td>
                     </t>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
           </div>
           <div class="footer o_standard_footer" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
               <div class="row text-center">
                   <div class="col col-12 text-center">
                       <ul class="list-inline">
                           <li class="list-inline-item">Page:</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="page"/>
                           </li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">/</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="topage"/>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </t>
</template>
````

```

esa es la estructura que le di al reporte en el xml y asi me lo esta imprimiendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi es como lo esta imprimiendo ya esta plasmando la informacion pero no de forma ordenada que podria hacer ahi para corregir eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es problema de la estructura html. Debes de agregar la etiqueta `<tr>` así:

```html
<tbody>
  <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="d">
    <tr>
      <td t-esc="d['date_order']" />
      <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['name']" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['otro_operation_type']" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['partner_id']" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['country_arrival']" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['freight_type']" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['invoice_amount_assured']" /></td>
      <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="d['seller_id']" /></td>
    </tr>
  </t>
</tbody>
```